# XBMC Performance

Tags: kodi, media-server

I want to transform my PI into a media center with XBMC.

Should I use an SD class 10 card or a USB stick to get the best performance out of it?

Comment: for my experience, sd class 10 cards are faster than most cheap usb sticks... you will propably not get any faster in terms of xbmc performance than class 10 with a usb stick, but your data will be more safe because of sd card corruption...

Comment: plus you should consider that the number of read/writes you can do in an SD is limited so, for the long term, I'd rather use an USB stick.